# Why can't rspec see my link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's my html:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Register / Login <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/sign_in"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> login </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/sign_up"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o-notch"></i> Register </a>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here's my expectation:

```
it { should have_link 'Register', href: registration_path }
```

However, the spec fails, even though the register link clearly exists. If I move the link out of the`<ul>` like this:

```
<a href="/sign_up"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o-notch"></i> Register </a>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Register / Login <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/sign_in"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> login </a>
        </li>
        <li>

        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The spec passes. Why is this?

Comment: Would it be possible that you have another link called "Register" without the registration path? "Register / Login" might be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using capybara.

Capybara will not detect hidden elements.
You need to click on a '.dropdown-toggle' element and then check the 'Register' link.
And this will only work when javascript driver is used (selenium, poltergeist, etc)

It's the good way - you're simulating a real user behavior.
However, you can try to [change capybara's behavior](http://makandracards.com/makandra/7617-change-how-capybara-sees-or-ignores-hidden-elements)

```
it "should have Register link", js: true do
  find('.dropdown-toggle').click
  expect(page).to have_link('Register', href: registration_path)
end
```